# Bootstrap 4 pass data to a remote modal

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm working with NodeJs and Express. I need to pass some data from the database (MongoDB) to a remote modal in Bootstrap 4. I know that Bootstrap removed the "remote" option in v4, but I need to have different contents in different files.
For now, I can send the data from the DB, open the modal with the remote content, but this remote content hasn't received the data from the DB.
This is my code:

The trigger button:

```
<a id="btn1" data-remote="myContent.ejs" data-foo="<%=some.data1%>" data-fighter="<%=some.data2%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1">Click me!</a>
```

The modal (in the same file):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4>My Modal</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modalR">
<!--REMOTE CONTENT GOES HERE-->
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group col-md-offset-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="form1">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The remote content (myContent.ejs):

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/fooAction" id="form1">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fooHere">foo</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fooHere" name="fooHere" value ="">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="fighter">
  <label for="fighterHere">Fighters</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="fighterHere" name="fighterHere">
      <option id="opFighters" value=""></option>
      <option value="Fighter1">One fighter</option>
      <option value="Fighter2">Another Fighter</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

The JS file:

```
//LOAD REMOTE-CONTENT (Bootstrap 4 removed the "remote" option)
$('body').on('click','[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
jQuery($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).data("remote"));
});
//PASS DATA TO CONTENT
$(document).on("click", "#btn1", function () {
var foo = $(this).data('foo');
var fighter = $(this).data('fighter');
console.log (foo); //Works! Console shows the correct data
console.log (fighter); //Too!
$(".form-group #fooHere").val(foo); //Doesn't show anything
$(".form-group #opFighters").val(fighter);  //Doesn't show anything
});
```

Where am I wrong?
Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `$(document).ready();` on `$(".form-group #fooHere").val(foo);` and `$(".form-group #opFighters").val(fighter);`?

Comment: The first time I tried it didn't work, but now it works perfectly. The question is that I don't know why needs `$(document).ready();`. Well, thanks a lot @webeno

Comment: I added it as an answer, and also provided an explanation, hope it clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the update script inside `$(document).ready();` - this will ensure the browser waits until the full document (including your modal) is loaded before executing what's enclosed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form-group #fooHere").val(foo);
    $(".form-group #opFighters").val(fighter);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it now! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer as the correct one! If you like the way it has been explained / formatted, feel free to also vote up my answer... not a must, of course, you do as you please, only if you did like it ;)

Comment: hahaha, sometimes it's just so surprisingly simple... ;) I'm happy I could resolve it for you!